# get the correct value of php variable

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

this is a stranger question

i have this for cicle

```
for($i=0;$i<count($certificazioni);$i++){
     $etc=certificazioni[$i];
 ....
    <img src="/cubo/addDocument.png"/ height="24" width="24" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEvento">
   }
```

when i click the image it open a bootstrap modal fade like popup

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addEvento" tableindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                <?php echo $etc; ?>
```

how i can intercept the correct value ? i receive the last value of $etc
there is a method to get te correct value of the cicle for ?

Comment: Use need to use javascript to get the value

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: @AfifZafri yes but how ?

Comment: @riccardoairone check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to use javascript to get the value. I'm not sure what $etc data is, but basically you need to create a javascript function, and pass the value to the function onclick image.

Example:

**PHP**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($certificazioni);$i++){
     $etc=certificazioni[$i];
 ....
     ?>
    <img src="/cubo/addDocument.png"/ height="24" width="24" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEvento" onclick="return viewImage(<?php echo $etc; ?>)">
    <?php
   }
```

**HTML Modal**

Add additional div to the modal code

```
<div id="outputHere"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
      function viewImage(image) {
        // do what you need with the data, which is in this case to append to the modal

        document.getElementById('outputHere').innerHTML = image;
        // this example is only to append the value. you can modified it to suit your needs (html code or anything)
      }
</script>
```

Comment: it doesnt work, i need to print $etc in the modal code

Comment: @riccardoairone once you get the $etc properly in you looping (refer my php code), you can then use js or jquery to simple append the value to the modal html.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to open a specific modal when an image in clicked and if so, then try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($certificazioni);$i++){
    $etc=certificazioni[$i];
    ....
    <img src="/cubo/addDocument.png"/ height="24" width="24" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEvento<?= $i ?>">

    <div class="modal fade" id="addEvento<?= $i ?>" tableindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
            <?php echo $etc; ?>
}
```

you should include the modal inside the for loop so that every image will have its own modal and when you click image 1 then modal 1 will open.. and you don't even need to use javascript for this.